# Create service connection and use the same in next stage of azure devops multi stage yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, multistage-pipeline

I have two yaml templates defined one for creating a docker registry service connection and second for deploying some stuff via container job. The second template uses the docker registry connection which is being deployed in first template. When I am running both the templates separately then both the stages are successful but when I run them in one azure-pipelines.yaml, it fails :

```
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. A service connection with name shared-stratus-acr-endpoint could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."
```

Is there any way like `dependsOn` or `condition` that we can provide in this situation?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you only authorized the service connection for the individual template\pipelines when you created them. The workflow is not super friendly.

What if you try and authorize the pipeline that is failing for that service connection explicitly. See [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-service-connection)

[image]

You could also just authorize the service connection for all pipelines depending on your security needs.